# Indeterminacy of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $f(z)=\frac{|z|(1+z^2)^4}{(z+1)^2}$ calculate $f'(0)$

I did:
$g(z)=|z|\rightarrow g'(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$ and $h(z)=\frac{(1+z^2)^4}{(z+1)^2}\rightarrow h'(z)=\frac{(z^2+1)^3[6z^2+8z-2]}{(z+1)^3}$
Now
$$f'(z)=g'(z)h(z)+g(z)h'(z)=\frac{z(z^2+1)^3(7z^3+9z^2-z+1)}{(z+1)^3|z|}$$

But $f'(0)=\frac{0}{0}$ which is an indeterminacy. What should I do?

ii)If $f(z)=2x+ixy^2$ verify the existence of derivative, and calculate that.
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2\neq 2xy=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0\neq -y^2=\frac{-\partial v}{\partial x}$$
My doubt that is the second item of the Cauchy-Rimeann first condition is fulfilled for x = 1, y = 1, but the second is not met for that point. I know that these conditions alone do not guarantee the existence of the derivative, but assuming that both conditions were met at x = 1 and y = 1 then the derivative would be at this point?

Comment: In (i), do you have reason to believe the derivative exists? Not completely sure what you're asking about (ii), but if $f = u + iv$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at a point $z_{0}$, then $f'(z_{0}) = u_{x}(z_{0}) + iv_{x}(z_{0})$.

Comment: @user86418 In i) the exercise just says to calculate the derivative at 0, but it may be that in fact it does not exist. The key point in ii) then is to check in which both equations points are met?

Comment: Here are two approaches for (i): 1. Show that $z/|z|$ has no limit at $0$ (looking along the real and imaginary axes suffices); 2. Note that $|z|$ isn't even real-differentiable at $0$, so the product with a (differentiable) rational function is not (real or complex) differentiable at $0$. For (ii), yes, it sounds like the question wants you to find where the C-R equations are satisfied.